# How to disable double space period for an HTML5 text input field in Android?

Tags: android, html, input, keyboard, space

Is there a flag to disable double space period for an HTML5 text input field in Android? None of the flags below turn it off.

```
<input style="margin:50px;width:200px;height:80px;font-size:16px;" id="my-input" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
```

Question is:**How to disable android's double space keyboard behavior in a web app?.**